# sum of the series $\sum e^{-n}\sin nz$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need to Find the sum of the series $\sum e^{-n}\sin nz$ and indicate where the series converges. Make an appropriate statement about its uniform convergence.

I was doing calculation like below, but did not get any right way about the series.

$f_n(z)=e^{-n}\sin nz$, Clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(z)=0$, at $z=(2m+1)\pi/2n$ we see $f_n(z)$ has maxima or minima? and $f_n((2m+1)\pi/2n)=0$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's formula?

Comment: Do you want to say $e^{inz}=\cos nz+i\sin nz$ ?

Comment: More useful here would probably be $\sin z = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})$. This allows you to turn the thing into (two) geometric series, which are convergent under certain conditions on the respective ratios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\sin(z)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})$. Thus, you can write your sum $$\sum e^{-n}\sin(nz)=\frac{1}{2i}\sum e^{-n}(e^{inz}-e^{-inz})=\frac{1}{2i}\sum e^{(iz-1)n}-e^{-(iz+1)n}.$$Now note that the convergence of $\sum a_n+b_n$ is equivalent to $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both converging or diverging; you can argue at least one of them *always* converges (although which one may depend on the region you are in), hence you can determine the constraints on the other one.